# Match label with color in raster colorbar

Tags: r, mapping, spatial, raster, colorbar

I would like to match colorbar labels with colors in a map when plotting `raster` objects in R.

Assume I have the following raster:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(matrix(runif(100), ncol=10))
```

and another raster:

```
r2 <- r/2

brks <- seq(0, 1, by=0.1) 
nb <- length(brks)-1 
cols <- rev(terrain.colors(nb))
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(r, breaks=brks, col=cols, lab.breaks=brks, zlim=c(0,1), main='first') 
plot(r2, breaks=brks, col=cols, lab.breaks=brks, zlim=c(0,1), main='second')
```

Problem:

If I plot:

```
plot(r, add=TRUE, legend=FALSE, axes=FALSE, lab.breaks=brks, 
     zlim=c(0,1), main='first',
     col=colorRampPalette(c("darkred", "red3", "orange", "gold1", "yellow", 
                            "lightskyblue","steelblue3", "royalblue3", 
                            "darkblue","darkblue"))(255))
```

and then intend to plot `r2` and I know:

```
breaks <- seq(min(minValue(r)), max(maxValue(r))))
```

How can I define values for `r` and `r2` such that they match the colors defined by `col` above?
Please plot `r` and `r2` with the same colorbar scale and assign values of choice to match those colors on the map. The values on the map must not necessarily be those assigned to the colorbar.

I need this kind of exercise because I am doing interpolation of station data. Kriging gives a good looking raster but underestimates the values. However, I have the max and min of the data I am mapping. Using the colors in `col` as above, I would like to assign values to the colorbar based on the colors on the map.

Many thanks,
Asong.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What is unsatisfactory about your `plot(r, ...); plot(r2, ...)` (or, more simply if extents and res match, `plot(stack(r, r2), zlim=c(0, 1), breaks=brks, col=cols)`)?

Comment: Hi jbaums, I got the answer by doing something like:p.at <- seq(floor(0.002431956) ,ceiling(0.33474011), length.out=6) # min and max of all datasets
#Moreover, if you want to define where the labels are located define the components of colorkey:
Plabels<-list(at=p.at)
PColorkey <- list(at=p.at,labels=Plabels)## where the colors change   ## where to print labels


p <- levelplot(histoprecipwin, par.settings=themes, margin=FALSE,xlab=NULL, 
               scales=list(x=list(draw=FALSE)),main=expression(Observed~bolditalic(bar(P))~~(mm/day)),zlim=c(0.01570962, 0.136705), colorkey=PColorkey )